# Paypal Parallel/Adaptive Payments issue in Laravel app

Tags: paypal, laravel-5.4, checkout

I have a platform which uses Paypal Paralell/Adaptive payments. A fee is deducted and sent to admin and the other part of the order is sent to the seller of a marketplace. Everything worked in test mode but in live mode all money is sent to the seller. But now when testing in live mode no split (fee) is sent to admin. Also in Laravel app admin the order is shown as "pending" instead of "processed" even the money is sent on paypal. All calculations in the admin dashboard stay at $0 and 0 sales.

I have no idea where to start searching for the error. Any ideas how to sort out the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Paypal Stopped adaptive payments. Now they are working on, Paypal for marketplace. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/

Fortunately, They are supporting adaptive payments for old installations. 
Cheers!